# Laravel showing 404 on all routes in Apache virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have two laravel apps that I wish to put on a live Apache server. The os is CentOs. I have followed this toturial to set up a virtual host: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7

When I try to visit my links, http://lara.ci/public/, all I get is 404 Not Found. Below is my sites-available file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.lara.ci
    ServerAlias lara.ci
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lara.ci/public_html/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/lara.ci/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/lara.ci/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Files for the app is in public_html folder. I even tried the approach below after searching all over but can't get it to work:

Set the following in httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess file in public seems to be working because when I try something like below, I get the redirection. Also mod_rewrite is enabled:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 / https://google.com
...
```

Appreciate assistance

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct, that you are going to http://lara.ci/public although your document_root already points to a public subfolder?

Comment: could you access http://lara.ci/index.php? Did you check permission on the files?

Comment: I can't access that either. Permissions set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fact that you are pointing the document root to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/lara.ci/public_html/public
```

Its should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.lara.ci
  ServerAlias lara.ci
  DocumentRoot /var/www/lara.ci/public_html
  ErrorLog /var/www/lara.ci/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/lara.ci/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't think that is where the problem is coming from. I have done as you say but get same error. On local development, I access my url like so `http://localhost/lara/public`

Comment: I am getting the message "Whoops, looks like something went wrong".

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, I realise that my hidden files didn't copy such as .env, .gitignore etc since I was using the `cp` command to copy my files. To fix the problem, I ran the command like below (Source: https://superuser.com/questions/61611/how-to-copy-with-cp-to-include-hidden-files-and-hidden-directories-and-their-con):

`cp -r /var/www/html/lara/.[^.]* /var/www/lara.ci/public_html` which effectively copied all my hidden files and everything is working smoothly.